# Linq query from list containing check for null condition

Tags: c#, sql, .net, linq

I am trying to use a Linq query to search for a match in a giant list (around 100k items). The search criteria needs to be the fields `StateCode`, `ChannelCode`, `EndDate`, and `ZipCode`.

However, the check for `ZipCode` is a little tricky. I need to pull back results given either of these two conditions:

- If `StateCode`, `ChannelCode`, and `EndDate` are a match and the matching record in the list has a `null` value for `ZipCode`.
- If `StateCode`, `ChannelCode`, `EndDate` and `ZipCode` are a match, with `ZipCode` being a defined value in both the list and comparison items

This is the query as I have it right now... which doesn't work. It constantly pulls back a list with a count of `0`. However, if I remove the section that searches for the `ZipCode` match, then I will get results.

```
List<ZipCodeTerritory> previousZips = allRecords.Where(
        z => (z.StateCode.Equals(item.StateCode) &&
        z.ChannelCode.Equals(item.ChannelCode) &&
        z.EndDate.Date == item.EndDate.Date &&
        (z.ZipCode.Equals(null) | z.ZipCode.Equals(item.ZipCode))
    )).ToList();
```

I have also tried replacing `z.ZipCode.Equals(null)` with `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(z.ZipCode)` and this still didn't work.

**EDIT:** I have also attempted the condition with `|` and `||` as the `or` operator. Neither work...

Just in case, here is the query written out into a SQL statement. This works as expected if I run it in SQL Server Management Studio.

```
SELECT * FROM ZipCodeTerritory 
WHERE StateCode = 'OR ' and ChannelCode = 'G' and EndDate = '12/31/9999' and (ZipCode IS NULL OR ZipCode = '00001')
```

**SECOND EDIT**

This is how I'm grabbing the record from the database. Again, since I didn't want to have to make multiple calls I wanted to grab all the record from the `ZipCodeTerritory` table and then search through that list.

```
List<ZipCodeTerritory> allRecords = (from z in db.ZipCodeTerritory
                                        select z).ToList();
```

Comment: It constantly pulls back a list with a count of 0 (mentioned in post above)

Comment: Just as a note, I think that the operator precedence of | comes before && (which itself comes before ||), so | and || are not strictly interchangeable.

Answer (score 1):

It should be;

```
(z.ZipCode == null || z.ZipCode.Equals(item.ZipCode))
```

Comment: Still no luck. Double checked by running the SQL query.

Comment: @NealR is this a Linq2SQL query? If so check the generated SQL code.

Comment: LINQ to Entities i believe

Comment: @NealR debug the code and make sure the `item` properties have correct values. When you are working with linq to objects for example string compares are case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean to have only one pipe symbol here? Two pipes ( || ) is logical or, single is bitwise or

```
    (z.ZipCode.Equals(null) | z.ZipCode.Equals(item.ZipCode))
```

Comment: operator `|` is not a bitwise OR when called on two boolean values, it's a non-short circuiting OR.

Comment: That's just my latest attempt, it doesn't work either way. I'll update the post. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since the `ZipCode` field in the database was 9 digits long, Linq placed four spaces at the end of each 5 digit zip code. So a zip code of '00001' would be a value of '00001    '. By placing a `.Trim()` like so I'm now able to get the expected result.

```
(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(z.ZipCode) || z.ZipCode.Trim().Equals(item.ZipCode)
```

Comment: If the field is `char(9)` it is actually the database that sets the spaces there not linq. But equals in the database ignores trailing spaces, C# does not. `Varchar(9)` would have been more appropriate in this case.